# What if subtracting the mean of the dataset causes overflow?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, dataset, mean

I have seen many cases in which one subtracts the mean of the dataset, aiming to "centralize" the mean in 0 (e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317114/what-is-the-purpose-of-subtracting-the-mean-from-data-when-standardizing), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743523/subtract-mean-from-image) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211436/why-do-we-normalize-images-by-subtracting-the-datasets-image-mean-and-not-the-c)).

In my case, I have a dataset composed by 256x256 images, where each position is a byte (and can assume a value between 0 and 255). I calculated the mean of each pixel across the dataset, but when I finally wrote the code to subtract the mean, I realized doing so would cause an overflow.

For concreteness, say my dataset is composed by only two "images" `a` and `b` as follows:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]], dtype = np.uint8)
In [2]: b = np.array([[9, 9], [9, 9]], dtype = np.uint8)
In [3]: dataset = np.array([a, b])
Out[18]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[9, 9],
        [9, 9]]], dtype = np.uint8)
```

Now my mean will be:

```
In [20]: mean = dataset.mean(axis=0)
Out[19]: 
array([[ 5.,  5.],
       [ 5.,  5.]])
```

And if I try subtracting the mean I get:

```
In [28]: a - mean
Out[28]: 
array([[-4., -4.],  # Notice, here, that the `uint8` type was apparently
       [-4., -4.]]) # casted, and these values "overflew" into negative values
```

I thought of "capping" in 0, but I noticed that this would happen in roughly half of my dataset, and it didn't look like a great solution. Any suggestion? (or is this just something that no one cares about anyway?)

Comment: Change your data to a representation that handles negatives?  Or don't standardize your data.  Is there any reason you're doing that besides that it seems to be best practice?

Comment: Why would you like the image to be stored in `uint` format?